# How to know for sure last tabs.onRemoved actually fired in Firefox WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a Firefox add-on using WebExtensions API. I listen to `tabs.onRemoved` event in my add-on, need to do something in callback function. Mostly it works fine.

**Problem is**, if there is only one Firefox window, and tab close causes window close, seems Firefox will quit without firing `tabs.onRemoved`.

I've tried:

- At Firefox `about:debugging` page, start debugging my add-on, add break point in `tabs.onRemoved` callback function, Firefox quit without hitting break point
- Send a message to *Native Messaging Application* in `tabs.onRemoved` callback, message not received at native application side
- Listen to `windows.onRemoved`. If there is only one window left, last `windows.onRemoved` seems not fired either

I thought it may be a Firefox bug. So I posted a bug at BugZilla (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1342322#add_comment). But Firefox guy said it is not a bug.

Is there any way to know for sure if `tabs.onRemoved` was actually fired?

I want to make sure my callback function finishes running before Firefox process quit, how to do that?

**EDIT:**

This is minimal reproducible example I created, it's based on Mozilla official example *tabs-tabs-tabs*. I removed unrelated part:

manifest.json

```
{
  "browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_title": "Tabs, tabs, tabs",
    "default_popup": "tabs.html"
  },
  "description": "A list of methods you can perform on a tab.",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/tabs-tabs-tabs",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Tabs, tabs, tabs",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

tabs.js

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  function callOnActiveTab(callback) {
    browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}).then((tabs) => {
      for (var tab of tabs) {
        if (tab.active) {
          callback(tab, tabs);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if (e.target.id === "tabs-remove") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab) => {
      browser.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    });
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

tabs.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <a href="#" id="tabs-remove">Remove active tab</a><br>
  <script src="tabs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
//onRemoved listener. fired when tab is removed
browser.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, removeInfo){
  console.log(`The tab with id: ${tabId}, is closing`);

  if(removeInfo.isWindowClosing) {
    console.log(`Its window is also closing.`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Its window is not closing`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that Firefox is quitting without hitting the breakpoint, or quitting despite hitting the breakpoint. It is not too unreasonable for Firefox not to stop the shutdown process when it hits a breakpoint in JavaScript code.

Comment: @Makyen I'm sure about it (tested quite a few times). Mozilla guys said: *This is only because the popup itself closes before the window does. Listeners in background pages and other remaining contexts are fired as expected.* I asked them how to make sure listeners are fired a week ago, then haven't respond yet.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: We're going to need a MCVE from you so that anyone working on this is sure they are dealing with the same issue you are attempting to solve.

Comment: @Makyen Please see my edited question. Added example.

Comment: Why are you listening for this from within a popup? It is not a reasonable test to see if the event happens when you are only listening from within the popup. Even if the last tab is being closed while the popup is open, it is not clear which would happen first: the popup closing (destroying any possibility of receiving the event), or the event firing. If you are actually wanting to test this, then you need to be listening to the event from an actual background script, not a popup. Frankly, I would have expected the popup to close any time you removed the active tab.

Comment: @Makyen I moved the listeners of `tabs.onRemoved` to background script. When closing tab causes last window closed, Firefox quit without hit my break point in callback of `tabs.onRemoved`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author or ColorfulTabs for Firefox. Here's how I handle this:

```
browser.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(onRemoved);
onRemoved(tabId, removeInfo) {
            browser.tabs.remove(tabId, function () {
                browser.tabs.query({
                    currentWindow: true
                }, function (tabs) {
                    tabs = tabs.filter(tab => tab.id != tabId);
                    console.log(tabs);
                })
            });
```